# Process Builder Time Dependent Action

Tags: process-builder, time-dependent-workflow, process

I want to send email to Account Owner if the Account have no activity since last 30 days. How do I do this in Process Builder. This has to be Recurring for all accounts. I have professional edition so I don't have time dependent workflow.

Comment: I don't think Process Builder enable time dependent workflow. I think  [Workflow rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_dependent.htm&language=en_US&type=0) are what you're searching for.

Comment: Have you tried using scheduled actions?

Comment: @RobinDeBondt But how can I make them Recurring ?